# MS Access, 3 Joined Tables, Top 5

Tags: ms-access

[Join Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1VqR.jpg)I have 3 Tables, Table 1 has Part Numbers (approx. 30), Table 2 has Part Numbers and Bulk Locations (approx. 10- 30 loc per Part Number), Table 3 have Part Numbers and PickFace Locations (approx. 0 - 5 per part number). 
How can I get the 30 Part Numbers from Table 1, Top 10 Locations from Table 2, Top 5 from Table 3.
I am hoping to show a report for users to action, but the bulk locations can make the report show too many locations and was hoping to limit the results from that table only.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do a query. Go to Create>Query designer and select your 3 tables. Now select all of your attributes which will be shown(Part numbers, Bulk locations and PickFace locations). Now in the top menu you will see a returns option. Select how many results you want to be shown,15 for example and then click run to see if you're satisfied with the query. When you're satisfied,save it and use it in your report.

Comment: Hi Kapobajza, I have tried the return option for the bulk location. the results only show for 1 of the part numbers not all 30. I assume I have screwed up the join some how.

Comment: Or maybe you messed up somewhere in your relationships. Do your tables have relationships between them? I was assuming they were connected through the Part Number attribute(primary key)?

Comment: Yes, I have added a pic to assist.